# Deleting the contents from specific repetitive columns Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with 8 columns. Some rows only differ in certain columns. I would like to delete the contents for the repeated materials. Let's say columns C1 and C2 are the keys and column C3, C4 are the values for one set C5 and c6 are the values for another set
here is what I have

```
|C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6|  
|A |C |E |F |H |I |  
|A |C |E |F |H |J |  
|A |C |E |G |H |K |  
|B |D |E |F |H |I |  
|B |D |E |G |H |I |
```

here is what I want

```
|C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6|
|A |C |E |F |H |I |
|  |  |E |G |H |J |
|  |  |  |  |H |K |
|B |D |E |F |H |I |
|  |  |E |G |  |  |
```

Comment: Is there a reason why in C3 C4 row 3 (idx 2) E G moved up a row?

Comment: Also why is H I in row 4 (idx3) not dropped in C5 C6  when it has a duplicate in row 1 (idx 0)? Or if you're looking for duplicates per key pair then why was H K dropped in row 5 (idx 4)?

Comment: @HenryEcker You are right, I changed the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try grouping by key columns and dropping duplicates from every 2 columns after:

```py
key_columns = ['C1', 'C2']

df = df \
    .groupby(key_columns, as_index=False, sort=False) \
    .apply(lambda g: g.groupby(np.arange(len(g.columns)) // 2, axis=1)
           .apply(lambda sg: sg.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

# For Display
print(df.fillna(''))
```

Output:

```
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
0  A  C  E  F  H  I
1        E  G  H  J
2              H  K
3  B  D  E  F  H  I
4        E  G
```